# How to enable the "basic" device in pocl?

Tags: opencl, pocl

I have  installed [pocl](http://portablecl.org/). 
`make check` shows all 145 tests passed.
The build shows that

```
--******** Enabled features:
......

-- OCL_DRIVERS (Drivers built): basic pthreads
......
```

But `clinfo` command shows only `pthreads` as the only device for the pocl platform. Is there a way to enable the `basic` device?
I want to add a custom opencl device to pocl. Understanding `basic` device implementation in pocl seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [pocl documentation](http://portablecl.org/docs/html/env_variables.html), the *basic* device hast to be enabled explicitly by setting the environment variable `POCL_DEVICES` to `basic`:

> POCL_DEVICES is a space separated list of the device instances to be
>   enabled. This environment variable is used for the following devices:
>   - **basic** A minimalistic example device driver for executing
>   kernels on the host CPU. No multithreading.

So you should be able to use the device by calling `POCL_DEVICES="basic" clinfo`.